# How to access specific values in a dictionary of type : [Int : [String]] in Swift?

Tags: swift, dictionary

I have a dictionnary of this type :

```
var emojiChoices  = [0 : ["","","","","","","",""], 1 : ["⚽️","","","","","‍♀️","",""]]
```

I'd like for example an other element to display the strings contained in the "0" key.

Thanks for Your help.

Comment: Using an indexed dictionary is an antipattern. Better use an array in this case.

Comment: What's exactly the question?

Comment: Unrelated to your question but I wouldn't recommend grouping your dictionary like this. A solution is to populate an array with struct objects which hold the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You access items in a dictionary by the key: emojiChoices[key]. Example:

```
var emojiChoices  = [0 : ["","","","","","","",""], 1 : ["⚽️","","","","","‍♀️","",""]]
let result = emojiChoices[0]
```

For a random key:

```
var emojiChoices  = [0 : ["","","","","","","",""],
                     1 : ["⚽️","","","","","‍♀️","",""]]

if let array = emojiChoices[0] {
    let randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(array.count)))
    let randomEmoji = array[randomIndex]

    print(randomEmoji)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, actually I'd like a variable to randomly choose between keys. I created a variable like :  var randomChoice = Int(arc4random_uniform(2)).